# Robot Framework: How to access a class property from a Robot Framework library

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

To implement a custom function, I am trying to access the `driver` property from the `SeleniumLibary` which looks like below in the python package:

```
class SeleniumLibrary(DynamicCore):

    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = "GLOBAL"
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_VERSION = __version__

    @property
    def driver(self) -> WebDriver:
        """Current active driver.

        :rtype: selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver
        :raises SeleniumLibrary.errors.NoOpenBrowser: If browser is not open.
        """
        if not self._drivers.current:
            raise NoOpenBrowser("No browser is open.")
        return self._drivers.current
```

I have create the webdriver using the `Open Browser` command like `Open Browser    url=${url}    browser=${browser}    alias=Test    options=${options}    executable_path=${driverPath}`.

I have tried multiple commands in the robot script to access the `@property` `driver` but it is not working:

- `Log    ${SeleniumLibrary.driver}`
- `${driver}=    SeleniumLibrary.driver`
- `${driver}=    Evaluate    SeleniumLibrary.driver`

**Error Message: Evaluating expression 'SeleniumLibrary.driver' failed: AttributeError: module 'SeleniumLibrary' has no attribute 'driver'**

Reference: https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/blob/master/docs/extending/extending.rst#id14

Comment: First, `driver` is not a class property, it's a property of an instance of `SeleniumLibrary`. If the instance of `SeleniumLibrary` is `slib`, access it with `slib.driver()`. Keep in mind that Properties in Python are like Getters in Java.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the solution using Robot Framework.

```
${SeleniumLibrary}    Get Library Instance    SeleniumLibrary
${driver}=    Set Variable    ${SeleniumLibrary.driver}
```